How do I retrieve the email and the envelope content
I am using the JakartaMail API in my Spring Boot application and I have already created a fetch profile and I am able to get the message content printed out on the command line. However, I need some help in retrieving the email content from the IMAP server and storing it into an array so my client can properly display it. Furthermore, I am only getting envelope items, i.e. from, to subject, etc., but my request are not working and my requests are always timed out.
I need help in understanding a flow to properly retrieve the email and the envelope content to then send back to the client.
Here is detail run down of the code I have thus far we will start with the email service that will fetch the email content:
    @Async
    public CompletableFuture<List<EmailResponseDto>> fetchEmails() {
        List<EmailResponseDto> emailResponseDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            prop.put("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
            prop.put("mail.imaps.port", "993");
            prop.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");
            prop.put("mail.imaps.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
            prop.put("mail.imaps.ssl.trust", "*");

            Session emailSession = Session.getInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
                }
            });

            FetchProfile profile = new FetchProfile();
            profile.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);

            Store store = emailSession.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("username", "password");

            Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            emailFolder.fetch(emailFolder.getMessages(), profile);

            for (Message message : emailFolder.getMessages()) {
                EmailResponseDto emailResponseDto = new EmailResponseDto();
                emailResponseDto.setSubject(message.getSubject());
                emailResponseDto.setFrom(message.getFrom()[0].toString());
                emailResponseDto.setSentDate(message.getSentDate());
                emailResponseDtoList.add(emailResponseDto);
            }

            emailFolder.close(false);
            store.close();

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(emailResponseDtoList);
    }

I am able to get a response back, but I get a 401 response, and my API client tells me "No Body returned for Response"

I am using an async function because I understand I will get a ton of emails. However, even if I limit the amount, I am not able to get a response back. I am wondering is my implementation or logic, correct? Should I instead be writing the email content to a file instead? 

EDIT:
I am to get the addres from the Emails however I cannot do it
@Async annotation
@Async
public CompletableFuture<List<String>> getEmails(String username, String password) {
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

        EmailProtocol emailProtocol = new EmailProtocol(username, password);
        List<String> fromList = new ArrayList<>();
        Session imapSession = emailProtocol.ImapSession();

        try  {
            Store store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect(username, password);
            Folder inboxFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inboxFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

            Message[] messages = inboxFolder.getMessages();
            for (Message m : messages) {
                Address[] fromAddresses = m.getFrom();
                if (fromAddresses != null) {
                    for (Address address : fromAddresses) {
                        fromList.add(address.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            inboxFolder.close(false);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fromList;
    });
}


If you want the entire content, then why do you use a fetch profile that only asks for the envelope? Also show the code you used to try and retrieve the content.

I apologize that is the content I want to retrieve from the emails just the envelope items. However, when doing so the requests times out. Hopefully this provides some clarity

below this line emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY); , add int messageCount = emailFolder.getMessageCount(); System.out.println("Total number of emails: " + messageCount); , for Debug , show mail count. find out why always timeout

I have provided a new edit to my original response it turns out I was able to get the email content like subject and from however, in the new example code I showed I am not able to complete such a task asynchronously
